# Cannot Create NUnit Unit Test From File On Visual Studio 2022 community

Tags: visual-studio, nunit

I have a solution file which contains two project, one is main project and the other is an unit test project.

I had them install both NuGet Package NUnit and NUNit3TestAdapter

[image]

However, I still cannot create nunit unit test near the function I want to test by the mouse right click event

[image]

As you can see, only MSTestV2 framework is detected.

[image]

**My question is**: How can I use the **NUnit** framework to create unit tests in Visual Studio 2022 Community?

Comment: I have read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/generate-unit-tests-for-your-code-with-intellitest?view=vs-2019#q-can-i-use-other-unit-test-frameworks-with-intellitest & https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/install-third-party-unit-test-frameworks?view=vs-2019. Not working.

Answer (score 0):

The TestGenerator extension has not been released for x64 which VS2022 yet.

What you do is to use command line tools:

Create a new folder for your test  projects.
The run :

```
dotnet new nunit
```

This will create a new NUnit test project.

Add this project to your solution and add a project reference from there test project to your other project "to be tested", and off you go :-)

UPDATE  May 2nd 2023:   Thanks for the comment (and reminder) and link
@tieson-t  ! Repeating the link here for visibility  https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NUnitDevelopers.nunittestgeneratorextension2022

Comment: Just a follow up - the extension is now available: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NUnitDevelopers.nunittestgeneratorextension2022